# mysql grouping, joins and order by problems

Tags: mysql

I need the result to look like this:

```
person_id   last_name   first_name  region_id   region name                         
  1         barnum         phineas      1       maricopa                                    
  2         loman          willy        2       pima                                        
  2         loman          willy        3       pinal                                       
  2         loman          willy        4       santa cruz                                  
  3         kay            mary         5       cochise                                     
  3         kay            mary         6       gila                                        
  3         kay            mary         7       graham
```

my code is this:

```
select `person_id`, `last_name`, `first_name`,
`Region_id`, `name` AS 'Region Name'   
from `sales_region`  
inner join sales_people  
on `person_id` = `person_id`      
group by  `region_id` asc, `person_id`        
having `person_id`in ('1','2','3')       
order by `person_id`,`region_id` asc
;
```

it gives me this:

```
person_id   last_name   first_name  Region_id   "Region Name"
1           barnum      phineas     1            maricopa
1           barnum      phineas     2             pima
1           barnum      phineas     3            pinal
1           barnum      phineas     4         santa cruz
1           barnum      phineas     5           cochise
1           barnum      phineas     6            gila
1           barnum      phineas     7           graham
2           loman       willy       1          maricopa
2           loman       willy       2          pima
2           loman       willy       3          pinal
2           loman       willy       4          santa cruz
2           loman       willy       5          cochise
2           loman       willy       6          gila
2           loman       willy       7          graham
3           kay         mary        1          maricopa
3           kay         mary        2              pima
3           kay         mary        3           pinal
3           kay         mary        4       santa cruz
3           kay         mary        5       cochise
3           kay         mary        6       gila
3           kay         mary        7       graham
```

I am not sure how to make it so it shows like it does above. I have tried messing with the order by and group by and i get the same kind of results. I am not sure how to narrow it down to how the results should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
select sales_people.person_id, last_name, first_name, sales_region.Region_id, trim(sales_region.name) AS 'Region Name'   
   from sales_region
   inner join sales_people_region on sales_people_region.region_id = sales_region.region_id 
   inner join sales_people on sales_people_region.person_id = sales_people.person_id

where sales_people.person_id in (1,2,3)
group by  sales_region.region_id, sales_people.person_id
order by sales_people.person_id, sales_region.region_id asc;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses! i get errors with both tries. there are no over lapping column information. person_id only exists in sales_people. region_id only exists in sales_region. i am only joining the tables so i can select from multiple columns. when i try to write two select queries i get errors.

Comment: don't you have a pivot table which contains both `region_id` and `person_id` columns? named like `sales_people_region` or `people_region` or similar?

Comment: i do have a table called sales_people_region which has both person_id and region_id. i didnt include it in the query because it seemed unnecessary.

Comment: it works perfectly! Thanks for helping a noobie out!

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it helped!

Comment: I appreciate that there are performance benefits associated with using GROUP BY in place of DISTINCT, but I think it's misleading to imply that one can simply be used in place of the other. In general, a GROUP BY clause is only required where aggregate functions are provided.